# In app turn by turn navigation

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an Android app and I get the co-ordinates for source and destination places. Now I have a button which on pressed, launches `Google Navigation` app with turn by turn navigation making my app go in background. I wanted to launch google navigation as a floating activity or an activity where I can set the `Window parameters` for it so that it is not launched in full mode but as half of the screen so that I can also view my app's activity. Is it possible to achieve this or should I consider using some other turn by turn navigation SDKs for Android?

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't allow multiple activities on screen at once-  at least not until N (Samsung and some other OEMs have SDKs that allow a limited amount of this prior to N, but it won't work on other devices).  So you'll need to find an SDK and embedd the map in your app.

Comment: So I can use the SDK and start the mapactivity by setting the window params?

Comment: You can't have two activities on screen at the same time, unless you're using Android N.  There is nothing with window params you can do.

Comment: Well I have made 2 activities at the same time before though the activity set with window params is in foreground overlaying the activity in background but still you would be able to see the background activity. Its really possible

Comment: You may manage to get something to work under some limited circumstances.  But its not designed to work that way, and don't expect it to work correctly.  For example an Activity that isn't foreground is in the Paused state.  Playing with window parameters wouldn't unpause it, so it would not have all of its handlers and receivers registered.  AN app doesn't expect to run in that state so I would expect it to crash like mad if you tried to interact with it.

Comment: Please see my question (requirement) . I just need to stay in my app when the navigation is launched. I really dont care it is in pause or unpause state. So I just need the navigation to be supported in my app and not as an explicit app

Comment: Your requirement is broken.  You're trying to do things that aren't supported in Android pre-N, and which shouldn't be expected to work reliably or maintainably.  You may get it to work on some platorms with some versions of some nav apps, but getting it to work across multiple platforms, multiple nav apps, and multiple versions will never happen.  Redesign your feature.  I'd be looking for a turn by turn nav api as an android library that you can embed in your app, rather than count on another app to display.